# PHP Ajax response is empty using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

At the moment I create a register "page". Here is the html code of the form

```html
<form class="register_form" method="POST" action="insert.php">
  <label class="label_register">Benutzername*:</label>
  <div class="input_group">
 <input class="input_register" id="register_username" name="username" type="text"/><span class="register_span">-</span>
  </div>
  <label class="label_register">Passwort*:</label>
  <div class="input_group">
 <input class="input_register" id="register_password_1" name="password" type="password"/><span class="register_span">-</span>
  </div>
  <label class="label_register">Passwort wdh.*:</label>
  <div class="input_group"> 
 <input class="input_register" id="register_password_2" name="password2" type="password"/><span class="register_span">-</span>
  </div>
  <label class="label_register">E-Mail Adresse*:</label>
  <div class="input_group">
 <input class="input_register" id="register_email" name="email" type="text"/><span class="register_span">-</span>
  </div>
  
  <button class="button button_register">Jetzt kostenlos registrieren</button>
  <p class="register_hint">
  * Pflichtfeld
  </p>
</form>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
var username_bool = true;
var password_bool = true;
var email_bool = true;
$('.register_form').on('submit', function(){
    if(username_bool == true && password_bool == true && email_bool == true){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                alert(response);
            },
        });
    }
    else{
        alert("---");
    }
    return false;
});
```

And here is the php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password_1"]) && isset($_POST["email"])){
    echo "response";
}
```

?>

Now I have sent the form, but the respone is empty. I use Firebug to debugg. What is my mistake? And I made also other mistakes?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be checking for a field named `password_1`

```
isset($_POST["password_1"])
```

while it's named `password`

```
<input class="input_register" id="register_password_1" name="password" type="password"/><span class="register_span">-</span>
```

You'll have to make sure the `name` attribute matches the value you're checking

Answer (score 2):

The problem i see is you check on `isset($_POST["password_1"])` and that is not in the form as you named your password field "password"

```
<input class="input_register" id="register_password_1" name="password" type="password"/><span class="register_span">-</span>
```

you need to check using `isset($_POST["password"])`

Comment: Thanks Thanks! That was the mistake